# View SolidWorks Drawings inside Delphi application

Tags: delphi, solidworks

Is there a way ( ole or component ) to view SolidWorks 10/11 drawings 
inside Delphi 10/XE/XE2/XE3? application?

I mean read .SLDPRT files, the project data part, material used etc...
the important part is tagged ...
but maybe a component to do this already exists...

Comment: solidworks itself has an activex component for reading/displaying the drawings, or are you looking for an alternative?

Comment: if you have a preview handler (preview in explorer) you can attach to it and show in your app

Comment: im not interested in draw, just material used...
anyway Rufo, what u mean preview handler?
all i have is .SLDPRT file, opening it with notepad i can see tags <PRODUCT> ..... </PRODUCT>
but nothing complete...
what i want is way to read the file or tags in Delphi 10++

Comment: Petesh, all i want is read the material used on solidworks drawings...
RAW MATERIAL of the draw...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to read information about the file without looking at the file data itself, there is the document manager API.

[SOLIDWORKS Document Manager API](http://help.solidworks.com/2016/English/api/swdocmgrapi/Welcome-swdocmgrapi.html?id=2515e0f58389406bb1a99bdd86551bc0#Pg0)